# Обращение к элементу ассоциативного многомерного массива javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как обратиться к элементу массива если знаешь его ключ?
Допустим есть массив:

```
var mpans =[
   alcatel = {
      name:'',
      brand:''
   },
   sony= {
      name:'',
      brand:''
   },
   antwo = {
      name:'',
      brand:''
   }
];
```

По другому массиву я узнаю название ключа. Допустим что название ключа лежит в переменной `cardan`. Нужно вызвать `name` и `brand` нужного элемента массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как у вас - не получится, нужно или так:

```
var mpans = {
'alcatel': {
   'name':"",
   'brand':""
},
'sony': {
   'name':"",
   'brand':""
},
'antwo': {
   'name':"",
   'brand':""
}};
```

или так:

```
var mpans = [];
mpans['alcatel'] = {'name':"", 'brand':""};
…
```

тогда обратиться можно вот так:

```
var result = mpans.alcatel.name;
```

или

```
var key = 'alcatel';
var result = mpans[key].name;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.